# Getting an array index from percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am building out an Angular2 Slider component and the current setup is that the value of the slider is a percentage (based off where the slider handle is from 0% - 100%). I have an array of n items and want the slider to grab the appropriate index from the array based off the percentage (where the handle is at).

Here is my current drag event (fired when user is dragging slider handle):

```
handleDrag(evt, ui) {
    let maxWidth = $('#slideBar').width() - 15;
    let position = $('#slideHandle').css('left');
    position = position.replace('px', '');
    let percent = (+position / +maxWidth) * 100;
    this.year = percent;
  }
```

The percentage is working correctly but am wondering how I should structure the algorithem to fetch the array index by percentage. So, if i'm at 50%, I want to fetch the array index 73 if the array length is 146.

Is there an easier way of doing this with JavaScript? I have done a similar component where I did a table approach but would like to figure out a way to do this without adding 'helper html elements' to the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your approach sounds fine, so getting the index would could be achieved by using the `.length` property of your array as follows:

```
var actualndex = Math.floor((array.length-1) * percentage);

// Where percentage is a value between 0 and 1
```

This should return an index between 0 and `array.length-1` depending on the percentage value.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

This answer didn't work for me.  I did some experimenting and found that `Math.round` is better than `Math.floor` in this situation, but using `Math.floor` with some additional logic is even better still.  For best results, try:

```
var index = Math.min(Math.floor(array.length * percentage), (array.length-1));
```

### Intro

I know this question seems to be answered, but I'm posting another answer because using the selected answer gave me unexpected results, and I want to save others from running into the same problem.

First of all, I want to clarify that if you only need an approximation, not a precise result, the selected answer will **mostly** work, especially for a larger array.

However, for smaller arrays, it frequently does not return the expected result.  For example, with an array size of 2, it always returns the first element (index 0) unless the percentage is exactly 100%.  Even 99% will return the 1st element (`Math.floor((2-1) * 0.99) == 0`).  In fact, 100% is the ONLY value that will yield the last index (no matter the size of the array).

##### Expected Results

By "expected" results, I mean, that if an array has N elements, each element is represented by `1/Nth` of the values from 0.0 to 1.0.  An array of 5 elements would be break down like this:

| **Given Percentage** | **Expected Index** |
| --- | --- |
| [0.00%, 20.00%) | 0 |
| [20.00%, 40.00%) | 1 |
| [40.00%, 60.00%) | 2 |
| [60.00%, 80.00%) | 3 |
| [80.00%, 100.00%] | 4 |

##### Algorithms

I looked at 3 different algorithms with various array sizes:

```
var indexFloor = Math.floor((array.length-1) * percentage);
var indexRound = Math.round((array.length-1) * percentage);
var indexCustom = Math.min(Math.floor(array.length * percentage), (array.length-1));
```

### Results

All 3 algorithms tend to the same results as the array gets larger, but the 3rd one always gives the results that I would expect.

Take a look at the results from arrays of sizes 2 and 5 (incorrect results in **BOLD**) ([Prettier version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMlTj.png)):

| Percentage | Floor (Size 2) | Round (Size 2) | Custom (Size 2) | Floor (Size 5) | Round (Size 5) | Custom (Size 5) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 15.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | **1** | 0 |
| 20.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | **0** | 1 | 1 |
| 25.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 30.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 35.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 40.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | **1** | 2 | 2 |
| 45.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | **1** | 2 | 2 |
| 50.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 55.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 60.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **2** | **2** | 3 |
| 65.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **2** | 3 | 3 |
| 70.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **2** | 3 | 3 |
| 75.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 80.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **3** | **3** | 4 |
| 85.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **3** | **3** | 4 |
| 90.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **3** | 4 | 4 |
| 95.00% | **0** | 1 | 1 | **3** | 4 | 4 |
| 100.00% | 1 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | 4 |

For size 2, both Round and the custom algorithm produce the expected results.  However, for size 5, only the custom algorithm does.  Specifically, the Round method has 85% selecting the 3rd element (I would expect 80% and over to be the last element) and 15% selecting 2nd element (I would expect that to require 20%).

We see similar results with slightly larger table sizes (Incorrect Results in **bold**) ([Prettier Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsQ3x.png)):

| Percentage | Floor (Size 8) | Round (Size 8) | Custom (Size 8) | Floor (Size 10) | Round (Size 10) | Custom (Size 10) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5.00% | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 10.00% | 0 | **1** | 0 | **0** | 1 | 1 |
| 15.00% | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 20.00% | 1 | 1 | 1 | **1** | 2 | 2 |
| 25.00% | **1** | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 30.00% | 2 | 2 | 2 | **2** | 3 | 3 |
| 35.00% | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 40.00% | **2** | 3 | 3 | **3** | 4 | 4 |
| 45.00% | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 50.00% | **3** | 4 | 4 | **4** | 5 | 5 |
| 55.00% | **3** | 4 | 4 | **4** | 5 | 5 |
| 60.00% | 4 | 4 | 4 | 5 | **5** | 6 |
| 65.00% | **4** | 5 | 5 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 70.00% | **4** | 5 | 5 | **6** | **6** | 7 |
| 75.00% | **5** | **5** | 6 | **6** | 7 | 7 |
| 80.00% | **5** | 6 | 6 | **7** | **7** | 8 |
| 85.00% | **5** | 6 | 6 | **7** | 8 | 8 |
| 90.00% | **6** | **6** | 7 | **8** | **8** | 9 |
| 95.00% | **6** | 7 | 7 | **8** | 9 | 9 |
| 100.00% | 7 | 7 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 9 |

The Round and Custom methods are very similar (especially for the size 10 array).  They are, in fact, identical up until 60%, which the Round method yields index 5, but the custom method correctly classifies that as index 6.  From then on, the Round algorithm is off by one.

### Conclusion

The original algorithm's use of `Math.floor` was correct, but the method used to ensure the result was a valid array index skewed the results because there are there are `N` elements, not `N-1` elements.  But when we use `N`, a percentage value of 100% yields a value that is outside of the valid range of `0 to N-1`.

However, by definition, 100% should return the last index of the array, and this can be enforced with a simple call to `Math.min`.  The result is this algorithm for determining an array index using a percentage:

```
var index = Math.min(Math.floor(array.length * percentage), (array.length-1));
```

###### Backup

1. [Complete table of all the tested array sizes and percentages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlbyU.png)
2. [Excel document I made for testing](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ar7dZ6Md3sVCnMRszZlJYlYVKeUZAQ?e=I3LY1d)